# Cordova ios app got stuck at loading screen in Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios-simulator

[image]

I have checked by opening simulator in safari but there were no requests to the domain or server. There are no errors in the console also
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 12.1
ios-deploy: installed 1.11.4
CocoaPods: installed 1.10.1

Answer (score 0):

You could try debugging the app using [Chrome web inspector](https://www.andreszsogon.com/debug-cordova-android-apps-with-ddms/) by adding console.log() messages for each startup process, so whenever your app stops responding you can guess at which point the failure occurs.